# Goroutines blocked by for loop?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have the following code which implements a worker queue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "time"
)

var (
    linkQueue chan Link
    scraperQueue chan chan Link
)

func CycleDirectory(page int) {
    linkQueue <- Link{Name: "asd"}
}

type Link struct {
    Name string
}

func (s Scraper) Start() {
    fmt.Println("Started")
    go func() {
        for {
            s.ScraperQueue <- s.Link
            select {
            case link := <-s.Link:
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", s.Id) + ": Received " + link.Name)
            case <-s.QuitChan:
                fmt.Println("Closed")
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}

func (s Scraper) Stop() {
    go func() {
        s.QuitChan <- true
    }()
}

type Scraper struct {
    Id int
    Link chan Link
    ScraperQueue chan chan Link
    QuitChan chan bool
}

func InitScraper(id int, scraperQueue chan chan Link) Scraper {
    return Scraper {
        Id: id,
        Link: make(chan Link),
        ScraperQueue: scraperQueue,
        QuitChan: make(chan bool),
    }
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}

func main() {
    linkQueue = make(chan Link, 2000)

    numScrapers := 2

    scraperQueue = make(chan chan Link, numScrapers)

    for i := 0; i < numScrapers; i++ {
        s := InitScraper(i+1, scraperQueue)
        s.Start()
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case link := <-linkQueue:
                go func() {
                    scraper := <-scraperQueue
                    scraper <- link
                }()
            }
        }
    }()

    CycleDirectory(1)

    // time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)

    for {
        // select {
        // }
    }

    // http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)

    // http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil)
}
```

Running this code using a for loop containing an if statement (or nothing inside), the scraper does not print a received message. Blocking using the ListenAndServe function from net/http, it prints the received message. Blocking using sleep for 1 ms, I receive the message. And putting a select statement in the for loop, I also receive the message.

Why is the for loop without a select statement not allowing for execution of the message sending in the worker queues, and how would I go about handling this. I need an if statement in the for loop to check if all the work has been done so I can exit the loop and end the program.

**Update**

Amd's suggestion is a solution to this problem. Here is my updated code using sync.WaitGroup
    package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var (
    linkQueue chan Link
    scraperQueue chan chan Link
    wg sync.WaitGroup
)

func CycleDirectory(page int) {
    wg.Add(1)
    linkQueue <- Link{Name: "asd"}
}

type Link struct {
    Name string
}

func (s Scraper) Start() {
    fmt.Println("Started")
    go func() {
        for {
            s.ScraperQueue <- s.Link
            select {
            case link := <-s.Link:
                Scrape(s.Id, link.Name)
                s.Stop()
            case <-s.QuitChan:
                fmt.Println("Closed")
                wg.Done()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}

func (s Scraper) Stop() {
    go func() {
        s.QuitChan <- true
    }()
}

type Scraper struct {
    Id int
    Link chan Link
    ScraperQueue chan chan Link
    QuitChan chan bool
}

func Scrape(id int, name string) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", id) + ": Received " + name)
}

func InitScraper(id int, scraperQueue chan chan Link) Scraper {
    return Scraper {
        Id: id,
        Link: make(chan Link),
        ScraperQueue: scraperQueue,
        QuitChan: make(chan bool),
    }
}

func main() {
    linkQueue = make(chan Link, 2000)

    numScrapers := 2

    scraperQueue = make(chan chan Link, numScrapers)

    for i := 0; i < numScrapers; i++ {
        s := InitScraper(i+1, scraperQueue)
        s.Start()
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case link := <-linkQueue:
                go func() {
                    scraper := <-scraperQueue
                    scraper <- link
                }()
            }
        }
    }()

    CycleDirectory(1)

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Comment: empty `for{}` loop uses 100% of a CPU Core. it is not good practice at all using empty for.

Comment: The busy loop will eventually block your entire program. (you also don't need a select when you only have a single case)

Comment: @Amd I need to stop the program from exiting until all the work is done. Is it possible to do this without a for loop. The for loop would constantly check until the work is done.

Comment: Use `select {}` to prevent main from exiting.

Comment: yes you may use `sync.WaitGroup`

Comment: @Amd Thanks, this seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @RiyadhRahman : Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `sync.WaitGroup` to stop the program from exiting until all the work is done.
Try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iM43UPwkZU):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var (
    wg sync.WaitGroup
)

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }()

    fmt.Println("Wait...")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```